# Get highest value per column without using union

Tags: sql, mapping, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Suppose, we have 200 students and 6 subjects. Input columns are

```
Name | Subject1 | Subject2 | ... through Subject 6
```

Output has only 3 columns:

```
Name | Subject | Highest Score
```

We need subject-wise highest scorer along with subject name and score as output. How will we do this at Informatica level? How will we do that at SQL level without using union?

Sample Data:

```
Name |Sub1 |Sub2 |Sub3 |Sub4 |Sub5 |Sub6
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---- 
A    |5    |67   |77   |6    |34   |43 
B    |54   |54   |32   |3    |23   |21 
C    |1    |23   |43   |45   |43   |21
```

Comment: Sounds like GROUP BY Subject with MAX(SCORE). Do you have more information like a sample data and desired output?

Comment: I'm guessing a conditional aggregation using `DECODE`

Comment: Sure. Consider this as Sample Data:
I/P : 

Name  Sub1 Sub2 Sub3 Sub4 Sub5 Sub6
A              5      67      77     6      34       43
B              54    54       32    3       23       21
C               1     23       43    45     43       21

o/p:

Name Sub_name  Highest
      B          Sub1          54
      A         Sub2            67
      A         Sub3             77
      C         Sub4             45
      C         Sub5             43
      A          Sub6            43

Answer (score 0):

Easy in Informatica, use a sorter with sort by set to Subject then score (ascending). Then Aggregator with sorted input group by Subject.

An SQL `GROUP BY` will take care of it i.e.

```
SELECT MAXSCORES.SUBJECT, MAXSCORES.TOPRESULT, RESULTS.STUDENT AS TOPSCORER 
FROM (SELECT SUBJECT, MAX(SCORE) AS TOPRESULT FROM RESULTS GROUP BY SUBJECT) AS MAXSCORES 
WHERE MAXSCORES.SUBJECT = RESULTS.SUBJECT AND MAXSCORES.TOPRESULT = RESULTS.SCORE
```